# How can I convert a date / time I get in as part of a json object into a date only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My json is returning:

```
json.Modified = "28/09/12 18:42"
```

is there a way I can convert this into:

```
"28/09/12"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dateOnly = json.Modified.substring(0, 8);
```

Comment: Technically a correct answer so I won't mark down, though the day he receives a date like 28/9/12, he's not going to get what he wants.

Answer (score 3):

```
var date = "28/09/12 18:42"
date = date.split(" ");
final = date[0];
```

Comment: +1.  Someone is taking into consideration single-digit months and days anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below code

```
var date = "28/09/12 18:42";
var arr =data.split(" ");
var newDate = arr[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```
var d=json.Modified.split(' ')[0];
alert(d); // 28/09/12
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/isizaj/1/edit).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the substr function if your string always matches the same pattern. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr

```
var cleanedDate = dateAndHours.substr(0,8);
```